# Anyone have any luck installing Oracle10g Client 64-bit 10.2.0.3 on Windows 7 x64 RTM?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, oracleclient

I am happy with Windows 7 RTM x64 overall as everything in my development environment works well with it except for Oracle Client 10.2.0.3 64 Bit version. I downloaded the latest release and as soon as I begin installing it, it stops with an error saying that it will install on Windows version 6.0 (Vista) but does not support Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7). There does not seem to be an option to ignore and continue. Anybody know a workaround for this? Cheers!

Edit: Changing compatibility to Vista or any of the other options does not seem to work either. I am also running as administrator and have administrator rights.

Fix: See my comment below for a solution!

Comment: Tried many solutions - looking like this doesn't work with usual solutions for 32 bit.  There is also no xp compat mode in 64 bit.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution for anyone else having the same issue. Just run the installer from the command line as shown:

setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs

and you will be fine, you dont have to set compatibility mode (doing this will probably cause it to fail).

I got this off the Oracle forums, thankfully from someone who tried to do it on Windows 7RC.

Answer (score 2):

Try right clicking on the executable, clicking properties, clicking the compatability tab and setting "Run this program in compatability mode for" to Windows Vista or something earlier.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention I tried that shortly after I posted and it passes the error but just drops out shortly after the check and before launching the installer. Oracle Client is a java app so there is no easy way to determine what is not running. At least for me that is.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was different, I was getting an error installing it on my Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise SP1. I would get OS not supported. Even when I tired the -ignoreSysPrereqs, it still found it as a prereq and failed it. So I modified the Oracle\stage\prereq\db_prereqs\db\db_prereq.xml and deleted the section that tried to verify the OS type as well as the service pack. Installed fine after that. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

- Run the application with the switch `ignoresysprereqs`
- Removed the Oraprereq jar file which is checking the prereqs during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an MSI you can use the Microsoft Orca tool to tweak the version requirements.

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2004/07/12/180792.aspx

You might fall foul of your license agreement by doing this.

Comment: its a java app, there is no msi in this case. Oracle have some unusual way of installing apps on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Quote
"I have found a solution for anyone else having the same issue. Just run the installer from the command line as shown: 
setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs
and you will be fine, you dont have to set compatibility mode (doing this will probably cause it to fail)."

I can confrim this solution it worked fine for me on a windows 7 enterprise edition and indeed don't set the compatibility mode cause it will fail, a second commandprompt will appear and the -ignoreSysPrereqs'" will be lost the causing the installation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

in some cases, (i dont knw exactly why), right click on the exe file, then going to the properties and then compatibility, you'll find the Compatibility mode disabled.
Try using the "Change setting for all users" some where below.